# Delete data from a specific partition in MS SQL 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, partitioning, query-performance

I would like to delete data from a specific partition using the partition ID. I got queries to truncate data from specific partition for SQL 2016 but did not find any query for lower versions.

I tried below query to delete only data from partitions with partition id 14 and 15.

```
delete from  partitiontable1 WITH (PARTITIONS (14 to 15))
```

Will the delete statement remove the partition itself along with data?

I want to keep the partition intact and remove data from specific partitions. Say, I have created partitions on a table, it has 5 partitions (1,2,3,4,5) and I want to remove data only from 2nd and 3rd partition.

Comment: This delete statement is invalid SQL Server 2012 syntax so it will do nothing but raise an error. Removing a partition and it's associated boundary is done with `MERGE` DDL. DML statements do not remove partitions. Is your question how to remove all rows from a partition and leave the partition intact or do you want to remove both data and partition?

Comment: I want to keep the partition intact and remove data from specific partitions. say, I have created partitions on a table, It has 5 partitions (1,2,3,4,5) and I want to remove data only from 2nd and 3rd partition.@DanGuzman

Comment: You can switch a partition to another table, truncate the table and then switch the partition back

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This delete statement is invalid SQL Server 2012 syntax so it will do nothing but raise an error.

Removing a partition and it's associated boundary is done with `MERGE` DDL; DML statements like `DELETE` never remove partitions.

The most efficient way to remove all rows from a partition in SQL 2014 and earlier versions is with `SWITCH` (SQL 2016 allows specific partitions to be specified with a `TRUNCATE`). To use SWITCH, create a similarly partitioned staging table with identical schema and indexes. You can then switch data between tables as a meta-data operation and then `TRUNCATE` the staging table.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
    SWITCH PARTITION 1 TO dbo.YourTable_Staging PARTITION 1;
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
    SWITCH PARTITION 2 TO dbo.YourTable_Staging PARTITION 2;
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
    SWITCH PARTITION 3 TO dbo.YourTable_Staging PARTITION 3;
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
    SWITCH PARTITION 4 TO dbo.YourTable_Staging PARTITION 4;
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
    SWITCH PARTITION 5 TO dbo.YourTable_Staging PARTITION 5;
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.YourTable_Staging;
```

Comment: I like the truncate table vs drop table, keeps it a little more reusable with less overhead of rebuilding it if it needs to be a repeatable task.

Answer (score 2):

This answer comes from [Cathrine Wilhemsen](https://www.cathrinewilhelmsen.net/2015/04/19/table-partitioning-in-sql-server-partition-switching/#switch3) whom I highly recommend reading and watching present if she happens to be at an event nearby. The code comes from her primarily, with a shoutout to [Itzik Ben-Gan](http://tsql.solidq.com/SourceCodes/GetNums.txt) and his function GetNums.

To summarize, you want to switch the partition to a new table and drop the table. You will still have your partition numbers afterwards, please see the below code (again primarily from Cathrine, I altered it slightly.) as a demonstration.

```
-- Drop objects if they already exist
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = N'SalesSource')
  DROP TABLE SalesSource;
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = N'SalesTarget')
  DROP TABLE SalesTarget;
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.partition_schemes WHERE name = N'psSales')
  DROP PARTITION SCHEME psSales;
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.partition_functions WHERE name = N'pfSales')
  DROP PARTITION FUNCTION pfSales;

-- Create the Partition Function 
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION pfSales (DATE)
AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES 
('2013-01-01', '2014-01-01', '2015-01-01');

-- Create the Partition Scheme
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME psSales
AS PARTITION pfSales 
ALL TO ([Primary]);

-- Create the Partitioned Source Table (Heap) on the Partition Scheme
CREATE TABLE SalesSource (
  SalesDate DATE,
  Quantity INT
) ON psSales(SalesDate);

 IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.GetNums', N'IF') IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION dbo.GetNums;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetNums(@low AS BIGINT, @high AS BIGINT) RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
  WITH
    L0   AS (SELECT c FROM (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1) AS D(c)),
    L1   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),
    L2   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),
    L3   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),
    L4   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),
    L5   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A CROSS JOIN L4 AS B),
    Nums AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rownum
             FROM L5)
  SELECT TOP(@high - @low + 1) @low + rownum - 1 AS n
  FROM Nums
  ORDER BY rownum;
GO
-- Insert test data
INSERT INTO SalesSource(SalesDate, Quantity)
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,dates.n-1,'2012-01-01') AS SalesDate, qty.n AS Quantity
FROM GetNums(1,1000) dates
CROSS JOIN GetNums(1,1000) AS qty;

-- Create the Non-Partitioned Target Table (Heap) on the [PRIMARY] filegroup
CREATE TABLE SalesTarget (
  SalesDate DATE,
  Quantity INT
) ON [PRIMARY];

-- Verify row count before switch
SELECT 
    pstats.partition_number AS PartitionNumber
    ,pstats.row_count AS PartitionRowCount
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats AS pstats
WHERE pstats.object_id = OBJECT_ID('Salessource')
ORDER BY PartitionNumber; -- 366000 rows in Partition 1, 365000 rows in Partition 2 and 269000 in 3 and 0 in 4
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SalesTarget; -- 0 rows

-- Turn on statistics
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;

-- Is it really that fast...?
ALTER TABLE SalesSource SWITCH PARTITION 1 TO SalesTarget; 
-- YEP! SUPER FAST!

-- Turn off statistics
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF;

-- Verify row count after switch
SELECT 
    pstats.partition_number AS PartitionNumber
    ,pstats.row_count AS PartitionRowCount
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats AS pstats
WHERE pstats.object_id = OBJECT_ID('SalesSource')
ORDER BY PartitionNumber; -- 0 rows in Partition 1, 365000 rows in Partition 2 and 269000 in 3 and 0 in 4
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SalesTarget; -- 366000 rows
```